# how to find id in column D, when found paste date from column g into textbox17

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, userform

Using userform1 to search column d for an ID, when found get ID date from column g and paste date in textbox17.... something like this but this code isn't working.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim id As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

id = TextBox16.Value
finalrow = Sheets("ALL P.O. INFO").Range("D1000").End(xlUp).ROW

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 4) = id Then
       Range(Cells(i, 7)).Copy
      TextBox17.Paste
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: States:  "Method 'range' of object'_global'failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  {Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim id As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

id = TextBox16.Value
finalrow = Sheets("ALL P.O. INFO").Range("D1000").End(xlUp).ROW

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 4) = id Then
      Me.TextBox17 = Cells(i, 7).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub}
```